# Convert array to matrix for CF

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

Currently, I have an array (in Pandas) with length of 3,000,000 the structure is
[***From***, ***To***, ***Width***] (for a graph). I wanted to change it to matrix size:
Where ***From*** as column, ***To*** as row, and ***Width*** as the cell value.
***From*** has 4,000 unique items. ***To*** has 300,000. And what data type should I use for the matrix to be accessible from excel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` for this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html